# Implement/extends class without implementing all methods

Tags: java, abstraction

I'm looking to have a method return a class `Job`, that has different methods based on the job type.
For example, the job type could be `BackupJob` or `RunCommandJob`. They don't share methods, but it's needed to get them from a single method, getJob().

Right now I have a normal class `job` that has the methods return `null`, without a constructor, since I construct the other classes (BackupJob or RunCommandJob for example) in the `getJob()` method.

What is the best way to get the different job classes while returning a single class?
example code below.
Job class:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCommands() { return null; }

public String getBackupGUID() { return null; }

public void setCommands(String... commands) { return; }

public void setBackupGUID(String backupGUID) { return; }
//Etc...
```

getJob method

```
public Job getJob() { 
if (JobType == RunCommandsJob) return new RunCommandsJob(...);
else if (JobType == BackupJob) return new BackupJob(...);
//and so on for all the other types
```

Example of the RunCommandsJob class, but it's the same concept with all the different types, but with unique method names.

```
public ArrayList<String> getCommands() { /* method */ }
public void setCommands(String... commands) {/* method */ }
```

Edit: A little bit more context.
I have a scheduler class, that can contain multiple Tasks. Each Task has it's own Job, that could be different things (for example, a RunCommandsJob). Job itself isn't used, but In the other classes I extend Job so that I can return a "Job" that is in reality a "RunCommandsJob", which has logic to edit it in the database/API.
It's complicated, but that's what I have to work with.

Comment: "*They don't share methods, but it's needed to get them from a single method, getJob().*" - I would highly advice to not use inheritance to realize this. Taking this approach sounds like a cascase of `if (... instanceof ...) { ... } else if (... instanceof ...) { ... }` down the road (i.e. tight coupling). I bet there is a way to give those classes at least one common method that could then be encapsulated in either an interface or parent class.

Comment: @Turing85 As much as I'd like to use just a single pair of set and get methods, it's not possible due to the fact that they can return strings, enums, or integers. Unless there is a way to return different types without overloading.

Comment: Where does `JobType` come from? Is it a member of the class, pass at construction time?

Comment: Please can you add code which shows how the class `job` relates to `Job`, and how that relates to `RunCommandsJob` etc?

Comment: So a `Job` gives you a `Job`? That doesn't seem like a particularly logical design. Sounds like you have a `JobFactory` that gives you instances of `Job`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define Job as an interface or abstract class. So you don't have to write default implementations and concrete classes must implement the methods.

Comment: I thought about that, but what would I do about all the other methods? Return null? throw an exception?

Comment: implement a default behavior or throw NotImplementedException.

Comment: @filliravaz Or define more interfaces for your concrete classes to implement, if those other methods are not really part of what being a “Job” means. Tip: Before worrying about your Java code, get *very* clear on the semantics of the problem domain. Don’t start coding until you have clearly defined business terms with relationships fully explained.